JS .some return not correct result
I have function that must returns class name related on condition
Here is function
  function getScheduleTruckDispatchStatusClass(truck) {
        if (truck.dispatches === undefined || truck.dispatches === 0) {
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-inactive';
        }
        if (truck.dispatches.some(x => x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.created || abp.enums.dispatchStatus.sent)) {
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-lgreen';
        }
        if (truck.dispatches.some(x => x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.acknowledged || abp.enums.dispatchStatus.loaded)) {
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-dgreen';
        }
        if (truck.dispatches.some(x => x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.completed)) {
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-active';
        }
        if (truck.dispatches.some(x => x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.cancelled)){
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-hidden';
        }
        return '';
    }

enum of statuses is like this
  abp.enums.dispatchStatus = {
    created: 0,
    sent: 1,
    acknowledged: 3,
    loaded: 4,
    completed: 5,
    error: 6,
    canceled: 7
};

in response from back end I see this status

So it must go to this block
  if (truck.dispatches.some(x => x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.acknowledged || abp.enums.dispatchStatus.loaded)) {
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-dgreen';
        }

But it always go to this one
 if (truck.dispatches.some(x => x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.created || abp.enums.dispatchStatus.sent)) {
            return 'schedule-dispatch-status-lgreen';
        }

How I can fix this?

foo == a || b needs to be written as foo == x || foo == y to correctly compare x.status. Not sure why you expect the .some() for acknowledged or loaded to be the one that runs though, since the status is 5 you'd expect it to be the one with completed, no?

yes, completed. Thank. this helps

|| abp.enums.dispatchStatus.sent is always true because 1 (from your sent: 1) is a truthy value. Try it in your console: 1 == true. Did you mean to write:
truck.dispatches.some(x => 
  x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.created ||
  x.status === abp.enums.dispatchStatus.sent
)

